# showing Popup box on Right click at JTree node swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jpopupmenu

I want to show popup box on a right-click at `JTree` node only, not for the whole `JTree` component.
When user right-clicks on a JTree node then popup box comes up. If he right-clicks a blank space in `JTree` then it should not come up. So for that how can I detect mouse event only for `JTree` node. I have searched over the net many times, but couldn't find a solution so please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

    final JTree tree = new JTree ();
    tree.addMouseListener ( new MouseAdapter ()
    {
        public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent e )
        {
            if ( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton ( e ) )
            {
                TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation ( e.getX (), e.getY () );
                Rectangle pathBounds = tree.getUI ().getPathBounds ( tree, path );
                if ( pathBounds != null && pathBounds.contains ( e.getX (), e.getY () ) )
                {
                    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu ();
                    menu.add ( new JMenuItem ( "Test" ) );
                    menu.show ( tree, pathBounds.x, pathBounds.y + pathBounds.height );
                }
            }
        }
    } );
    frame.add ( tree );


    frame.pack ();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setVisible ( true );
}
```

Comment: It is better to use the `MouseEvent#isPopupTrigger` then the `isRightMouseButton` method.

Comment: That actually depends on the situation. But for the default popup menus yes, its better.

Comment: +1, wish I knew that much about `JTree` :-) . For me it's a nice answer :-)

Comment: For better UX you can menu.show ( tree, e.getX(), e.getY());

Answer (score 1):

Just because I stumbled upon this recently and I think it's a little bit easier than the existing answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JTree tree = new JTree();

    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Test"));
    tree.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
    frame.add(tree);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: It is definitely easier, but I recall having some issues with it on some specific Swing components. Plus you have no control over how, where and when this menu is displayed - you can only modify contents of the menu. The code that displays menu in your example is hidden deep within L&F implementation (not even component itself or its UI) and it checks `event.isPopupTrigger()` by default which, among other possible issues, doesn't work on some systems.

Comment: I'm not that much of a Swing-pro, I just thought the easy solution should not be kept secret if it works in most cases... Thanks for pointing out the issues

Comment: Your approach will show popup if user click everywhere inside JTree, which did not wanted in this question.